# Node.js + socket.io using socket object in a model

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Why I am getting this message?

My app.js

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('login', function(data) {
        var player = new Player(socket, name)
    })      
})
```

My player.js

```
var Player = function(socket, name) {
    this.socket = socket
    this.name_ = name
};
```

I can't resolved this and I have not an idea how can I solve this.. Is this a issue?

Error message:

> Missing error handler onsocket. RangeError: Maximum call stack size
>   exceeded at Object.hasOwnProperty (native) at _hasBinary
>   (/Users/macbook/Desktop/batak/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/has-binary/index.js:49:45)
>   at _hasBinary
>   (/Users/macbook/Desktop/batak/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/has-binary/index.js:49:63)
>   at _hasBinary
>   (/Users/macbook/Desktop/batak/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/has-binary/index.js:49:63)
>   at _hasBinary
>   (/Users/macbook/Desktop/batak/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/has-binary/index.js:49:63)
>   at _hasBinary
>   (/Users/macbook/Desktop/batak/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/has-binary/index.js:49:63)
>   at _hasBinary
>   (/Users/macbook/Desktop/batak/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/has-binary/index.js:49:63)
>   at _hasBinary
>   (/Users/macbook/Desktop/batak/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/has-binary/index.js:49:63)
>   at _hasBinary
>   (/Users/macbook/Desktop/batak/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/has-binary/index.js:49:63)
>   at _hasBinary
>   (/Users/macbook/Desktop/batak/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/has-binary/index.js:49:63)

Comment: What are your intentions when storing the socket in the Player object? You could pass socket.id instead and then comunicate to that player specifically using  `io.to(player.socket).emit('foo');`

Comment: @EMX I am making online card game. I need to reach socket in player.js https://github.com/vincentwoo/setgame/blob/master/game.js#L97 there are an example but I could not do it.

Comment: https://github.com/vincentwoo/setgame/blob/master/server.js#L99

Comment: the problem is that :) how can I push "socket to it each player

Comment: Why don't you show more code? It seems like you are attempting to use code that you don't fully understand.

Comment: Did you manage at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If storing the `socket object` inside the `player object` is giving you problems,
 why don't you store the socket's handshake unique id?

Here I leave an example of this approach, including a little example for your app to have fast access to the player objects by using the socket.id as the index for searching the storage.

```
var _players = {};
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('login', function(data) {
        var csid = socket.id;
        var player = new Player(csid, name);
        _players[csid] = player; //Store the player in memory
    });      
    //using the memory : example (prints name of player using socket.id)
    socket.on('ask_name', function() { 
         var csid = socket.id;
         console.log(_players[csid].name);});
});
```